# Is there a way to know the name of the model used in a directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, directive, angular-ngmodel

Suppose I have the following directive:

```
.directive("counter", function () {
            return {
                restrict: "E",
                scope:{
                    bindModel:'=ngModel'
                },
                templateUrl: "/directives/countertemplate.html"
```

and template:

```
<div id="counter" ng-class="{true: 'twitter-counter'}[bindModel.length > 140]">
  {{140 - bindModel.length}}
</div>
```

is there a way I could know the name of the model passed into the directive:

```
 <counter ng-model="twitterPost"></counter>
```

for example I would like to know from the context of the template that "twitterPost" was sent to the template, so I could perform a different set of logic than "facebookPost"

Comment: Use a different attribute

Answer (score 1):

In link function you can retrieve all attributes from the element. **[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/q4maE92SG8fxMrTbOp79?p=preview)**

```
template: "<div ng-show='isTwitterPost'>Twitter</div><div ng-show='!isTwitterPost'>Facebook</div>",
link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
  $scope.isTwitterPost = attrs.ngModel === 'twitterPost';
}
```

You should add extra attributes.

```
 <counter ng-model="twitterPost" is-twitter='true'></counter>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do it in angular way, passing object which carries all the info you need and process the logic in directive, for example
in this fiddle: 
    `//jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/6052/`